# Stuck while &amp are there

Tags: java, android

I've got a problem with &amp when I use XML parsing with webservices which developed in php. I get a bad XML formate error. All problems are connected with `&amp`. So my question is how can I ignore or replace &amp character while I'm reading xml file?

Please help me out this...

Comment: Before you try to work around, &amp; needs a semicolon is the xml format valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should preprocess the &amp, changing it to & and then parse the XML data.

```
private String preprocessXml(String xmlData) {    
  return xmlData.replace("&amp;", "&"); 
}
```